# Challenge: How to efficiently fill data gaps in an sparse Flex ArrayCollection?

Tags: apache-flex

I have an ArrayCollection of Objects. Each Object with three attributes:
CustomerID, Income and Date
My goal is to chart this data for each customer (or a couple together) in a Income by Date LineChart display. Selection of customers is done with ArrayCollection filters.
Data is fetched from an SQL database, however, each customer has some data points missing. If there was zero income on August 8, 2010 there will be no entry for that.
Charting the ArrayCollection as is, is misleading because there is no indication of the missing data points.

One way to solve this is to artificially add zero points for the missing dates for each customer. However, this would explode the data set (and impact performance).
Can anyone help with correctly charting this sparse ArrayCollection without adding a lot redundant data points?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Have you thought about handling this in SQL?

Comment: Yes I did. That would add thousands of thousands of redundant points and explode the data set so I am saving it for the last option.
I was thinking more of adding a "silent" series to the ArrayCollection with data points before charting. I tries adding all date points which works fine where the actual data set is missing that point but creates a double point on the chart when the two series include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compromise I choose is to fill out the gaps specifically for the customers in display.
At init() I build an index for each customer entry by the date. When displaying customer data I go through the index, identify missing dates and fill them out in the ArrayCollection.
I pay in a bit performance for each rendering of the chart but save a lot of memory.